# Chrome extension: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am currently playing around with Chrome Extensions and had some fun so far, but now I ran into some issues and I tried solving it for the last few hours, but I am still stuck. It somehow seems like I cannot establish a connection between my HTML file and the button specified there and the corresponding js script which performs the actual action.

Manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test Extension",
    "description": "Some text",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Some title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="logo">
            <img class="logo-icon" src="modal-image.png" />Modal Title
            <span class="version">(1.0.0)</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Description in modal</p>
    </div>
    <button id="button1" >Check</button>
    <script src="popup.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('button1');
    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function () {

        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (activeTab) {
            chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, tabs => {
                let url = new URL(tabs[0].url);

// some code which manipulates the current URL and opens a new tab with the new URL

                chrome.tabs.create({ url: myNewUrl });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This is the error I see in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Would you have any idea? Note: I am not a programmer at all and just discovering chrome extensions and javascript :)

Comment: 1) Remove `background` section from manifest.json. The background script runs in a hidden background page. It's like a hidden tab that has its own life cycle: it runs when the extension is loaded, installed, re-enabled, or when resumed in case the background script was declared with "persistent":false. You don't need it. 2) Remove chrome.browserAction.onClicked - it won't work when default_popup is used. You don't need it anyway because the browser_action icon was already clicked, which is why the popup is shown. The popup runs anew each time the icon is clicked.

Comment: amazing, many thanks!! That worked very well. Must have been mostly related to your 2nd point because I tried removing the background already based on what I have read in other chats.